# Parsing a HTML Table gets empy soup with beautifulsoup and request

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to get all the table in this `url = "https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2020/subject-ranking/life-sciences#!/page/0/length/25/sort_by/rank/sort_order/asc/cols/stats"` in a DataFrame (821 rows in total, need all the table). The code I'm using is this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
url = "https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2020/subject-ranking/life-sciences#!/page/0/length/25/sort_by/rank/sort_order/asc/cols/stats"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup) # It doesn't print anything
```

My idea is to get the info in soup and then look for the tag `<script> jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"basePath": ...` and get inside the followig json link `https://www.timeshighereducation.com/sites/default/files/the_data_rankings/life_sciences_rankings_2020_0__a2e62a5137c61efeef38fac9fb83a262.json` where is all the data in the table. I already have a function to read this json link, but first need to find the info in soup and then get json link. Need to be in this way because I have to read many tables and get the json link by inspectioning manually is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the following regex pattern which finds the  desired string after "url"

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
    r = s.get('https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2020/subject-ranking/life-sciences#!/page/0/length/25/sort_by/rank/sort_order/asc/cols/stats')
    url = re.search('"url":"(.*?)"', r.text).groups(0)[0].replace('\/','/')
    data = s.get(url).json()
    print(data)
```

---

[image]